# A looping statement in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I have this array and I can't seem to figure out how to form a for looping statement to be able to display these values in a list.

```
float array1[]   = {30 , 0.81 , 0.16 , 30 , 2813 , 58 , 8.4 , 0.61};
```

I tried figuring it out but it just kept being a syntax error

```
for (array1; array1 <= 8; array1++ )
   printf("%f\n", array1);
```

any suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array1` is the name of the array and not a variable that You want to increment!

```
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++ )   printf("%f\n", array1[i]);
```

Comment: `array1` **is** a variable, it's just not a modifiable lvalue.

Comment: I said that this is a variable... there is just no point in incrementing it(at least at this level)

Comment: It's an amusing term, `const variable`... (`array1` cannot be modified, `*(array1+n)` can be.)

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(array1)/sizeof(float); i++)
    printf("%f\n", array1[i]);
```

Comment: `int i = 0` in the for loop won't work in C

Comment: @pivovarit You're late by 14 years, C99 has been released in 1999.

Comment: printf("%f\n", array1[i]);

Answer (score 0):

You need an index into your array:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) { // SIZE should be 8.
    printf("%f\n", array1[i]);
}
```

Think of your array as a contiguous section of memory that contains SIZE blocks of data. The index `i` is used to access the value stored in each block.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;
for (i; i <= 8; i++)
    printf("%f\n", array1[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int length = sizeof(array1) / sizeof(float);
for(int i = 0; i< length; i++)
{
 printf("%f\n", array1[i]);
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(array1) / sizeof(array1)` == 1

Comment: I think, it's better practice/habit to use `sizeof(array1) / sizeof(array1[0])`... instead of word `float`..

Answer (score 0):

try the following code,

```
float *ind;
for (ind=array1; ind < array1+8; ind++ ){
    printf("%f\n", *ind)
}
```